# Remove comments in css bundle without minifying the file

Tags: css, .net-core, bundle

Is there a way to remove comments in a CSS bundle under ASP.NET Core MVC without minifiying?
This is how my **bundleconfig.json** file looks like:

```
[
  // *** CSS Bundles ***
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/bundles/css/base-bundle.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/font-imports.css",
      "wwwroot/css/src/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "wwwroot/css/css/styles.css",
      "wwwroot/css/customStyles.css",
      "wwwroot/css/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css",
      "wwwroot/css/src/lib/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css",
      "wwwroot/css/base.css" 
    ],     
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "commentMode": "none" //Here is what I though that it would work
    }
  }
]
```

Each of the referenced files has comments into it.
So I want to remove the comments that you are able to see in the browser console but without minifying the file.

I saw that if you set **"minify":{ "enabled":true }** the comments are removed as expected, but with **"minify":{ "enabled":false}** the comments are still there.

Am I missing some configuration? Is there a known issue?

Comment: you are seeing css comments in the browser console ?

Comment: yes, well, I see it under the bundle that is generated.

Comment: your json looks like its not formated correctly, is that a 1to1 copy of your setup ? the example from the github page looks a bit different

Comment: yes, sorry dirk, that was not the problem. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes is possible I find documentation here:
https://lore.chuci.info/taurenshaman/json/3108b142d7b44f91bb7500820d44378f

for JS files

```
 {
    "outputFileName": "Bundle/dependencies.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Bundle/dependencies.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "preserveImportantComments": false
    }
  }
```

For CSS files:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "Bundle/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Bundle/site.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "commentMode": "none"
    }
  }
```